# update of multiple columns

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I flipped through the official doc. and the existing threads but couldn't figure out when would the following trigger execute :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_TS_TRANSPORT_AFTER 
   AFTER INSERT OR
         UPDATE OF iud, addressid, idd, rld, pickupaddressid, vessel
   ON chassitransports
   REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
   FOR EACH ROW
.
.
.
```

1. Any one of the columns is updated
2. ALL the columns are updated

Since the updates occur from an external db, I cannot test the above scenarios :|

Comment: My understanding it will fire after inserting *any* row OR after updating *one of the mentioned* columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should fire after INSERT of rows or after UPDATE of any of the mentioned column. See below example :

```
---- Create sample Tables
CREATE TABLE temptable1 (regNo VARCHAR2(20), timec TIMESTAMP(6));

create table TEMPTABLE2
(
  idx    NUMBER,
  regno  VARCHAR2(20),
  eventb VARCHAR2(20),
  timec  DATE,
  rfid   NUMBER
);

----- Trigger definition 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_update_tr
AFTER UPDATE OF timec, regNo ON temptable2

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO temptable1
VALUES(:NEW.regNo,
:NEW.timec);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);

END;

------ Fire update statement ----
UPDATE temptable2 
SET regNo = 'VISIT0000011'
WHERE timec IS NULL;
```

and it executed successfully.